# How to use ARRAY FORMULA with COUNTIF

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, countif, flatten

Just want to get this in array formula but I don't know how to script this is the sample

```
=countif(G7:X7,"A")+(countif(G7:X7,"L")/2)
```

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16WyE8yfN4RCvqNkCv8WBQfrurqWtpXplj46hoox6bvM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: try again, sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(C5:J9="A", 1, IF(C5:J9="L", 0.5, 0)), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C5:J9), 1, 1, )))
```

[image]